# Angular 8 and Stripe.js V3's loadStripe: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@stripe/stripe-js/types/index'

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe as a payment processor, and they provide a library that allows developers to create secure "elements" (credit card inputs and such).  To remain A-rated PCI compliant, the library they provide, Stripe.js, cannot be bundled: It must be included from their site: https://js.stripe.com/v3.  As such, they provide a helper function, `loadStripe`, that can be used to dynamically include the aforementioned script.  (It just adds a `<script>` tag and waits until it's loaded under the hood.  Nothing fancy.)

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js

I was able to install that library via NPM and get Stripe working in my Angular 8 project.  I made the `loadStripe` function a provider so that I can mock it out during testing.  Here's a slimmed-down version of what I'm doing.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],  
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],  
  providers: [
    {provide: loadStripe, useValue: loadStripe},
  ],  
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

It works fine.  I can use `loadStripe` in my services and I can mock it out in my unit tests.  But when I try to do a *production* build (`ng build --prod`) I get a nasty, cryptic error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@stripe/stripe-js/types/index' in '/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/src/app'
resolve '@stripe/stripe-js/types/index' in '/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/src/app'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/package.json (relative path: ./src/app)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/
        using description file: /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/package.json (relative path: .)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/package.json (relative path: ./@stripe/stripe-js/types/index)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.tsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index doesn't exist
      /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/src/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/<MY-USER>/temp/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/<MY-USER>/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules
        using description file: /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/package.json (relative path: ./types/index)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.ts doesn't exist
            .tsx
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.tsx doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.js doesn't exist
            as directory
              /home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index doesn't exist
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.ts]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.tsx]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.mjs]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.js]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/src/app/node_modules]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/src/node_modules]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/node_modules]
[/home/<MY-USER>/node_modules]
[/home/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.ts]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.tsx]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.mjs]
[/home/<MY-USER>/temp/test-stripe/node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/types/index.js]
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 13:0-52 14:2720-2733
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts
```

I can provide a StackBlitz if needed, but the app referenced above is literally the default `ng new test-stripe` with `npm install @stripe/stripe-js@1.2.x`.

FWIW, `ng build` and `ng serve` work as expected, it's just the prod build that fails.  If I remove the `loadStripe` provider the app builds (i.e. if I just import `loadStripe` in my services directly).

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Seems related to this discussion https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11392. Sorry not super familiar with Angular but that looks exactly like the issue you are having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found three ways to fix this.

1. Per the [Angular Package Format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview#heading=h.k0mh3o8u5hx), adding a "typings" entry to `@stripe/stripe-js` module corrected the problem.  (There's already a "type" entry in the module's `package.json` file, but evidently that's not supported in Angular 8.)
2. Manually add a path for @stripe/stripe-js in the `compilerSettings` section of `tsconfig.json` file.

```
"paths": {
  "@stripe/stripe-js": [
    "node_modules/@stripe/stripe-js/dist/stripe.js"
  ]
}
```

3. Upgrade to Angular 9, which is the path I ultimately went with.